power failure during update
There have been several questions with regard to power failure during update.  Even going back 10 years, comments/answers suggest an untimely power failure could result in loss of system.
Given my system has a UPS which in a bad case situation, might supply in excess of five minutes running at the time of a power failure and if just before that I have initiated an apt upgrade.

At what point(s) during that update process might I kill that update and yet preserve enough of my system so that after the power restore I can expect the key portions of the system (the OS of course, network communication and the GUI) to work.  Perhaps the opposite would be more appropriate to ask - when during update should I definitely NOT attempt to kill an update.
Upon full power restoration, would a simple apt update do, to finish the complete update?

This is specifically to a typical Xubuntu (currently 24.04 but, that may change when 26.04, 28.04 etc. becomes available).  The desktop environment is powered by a small UPS which can keep the system running for more than 5 minutes without external power.  It is understood that apt upgrade should not be done if there is a threat of or during weather events that cause power disruption.

You've provided no Ubuntu product details; and in my own experience the problems on power interruption vary significantly depending on what was actually happening during the exact nanosecond of outage.. ie. was the machine reading disk? writing disk etc.. were capacitors on drive in good health & could cope with safely completing their task or not? were hdd or ssd's involved (very different power requirements etc), and more...  In many cases its reboot & continue, other times you have a problem caused by what machine was writing but failed to complete due to outage...

@guiverc - If it was an immediate power loss reading/writing, drive in good health etc. would matter.  I would never plug a desktop system directly into the house power - I always use a UPS.  This question is WHEN, within a five minute interval, killing the process running the apt-upgrade would not brick the system.  Sometimes an apt-upgrade from start to finish takes several minutes to complete.  If I pulled it down while Libreoffice, Chrome or Firefox was being updated, that's not hard to repair.  If th process was in the middle of updating the kernel when I killed the process - that's bad.

continuing my comment.  Picture the room lights out.  The monitor, network and system still running, the UPS alarm going off and a quick query of remaining battery power showing 5 minutes capacity.  I can see the details of the active process as it performs an apt upgrade.  I know it won't finish.  A sudo kill -9 xxxx (where xxxx is the process running the update) will stop the process.  As I watch the details of the apt upgrade process in one command line session with my finger hovering over the ready kill process in another command line session

If it's updating Chrome, I'm probably OK to kill the process.  If it's updating the grub, I better let it continue to something not as critical to restarting the system.

You're sort of missing where I'm talking about, which isn't thinking about package level, ie. an upgrade of a wallpaper package could be as bad as other system packages IF the write that didn't complete was to the file-system meta data/table, rather than data blocks... ie. you need to be think lower level than packages... sector specific; as updating any data on system may not need change to anything but user area of disk (less risky, no filesize change) but may involve change of allocation meaning significance to data loss could be far higher due to need to change file-system details.

@guiverc I think you're saying any time any process is killed with -9, the disc is at risk.  Here, the question is about a system that is going to go down, can I lessen the recovery damage by choosing when in the apt upgrade to have it die vs. allow the system to run on until the battery is exhausted. Allowing the system to go to battery exhaustion would also run the risk of uncontrolled stop vs perhaps two commands: sudo kill -9 [the update] followed by sudo shutdown -P now

No I'm talking about power failure which can prevent the OS from sync & other safe processes; which does not apply to kill -9 where the OS is actually functioning... ie. with power outage you need to think hardware levels (sector write being the closest to the OS that is involved; but consequences of bad write due to power-loss in middle of process as dictated by OS to the actual hardware...)  Even kill -9 is still controlled (by OS), where I'm talking hardware & actual sector writing; what sector was being written is key (ie. data area of disk? or due to filesize change fs metadata)

power outage introduces a undefined nature in what the electronics will do, and so think that level and what instructions are being executed... FAR lower than package level, as its what part of the code was being executed that matters, not the detail as to what it was (ie. even wallpaper change could be destructive if power loss occurs when file-system metadata was being written on outage & thus file-system itself was damaged due to incomplete write operation on disk)..    I'll suggest avoiding making any file-system changes to directories, far more than data areas of disk

@guiverc I agree if the power failed, your comments are quite correct.  This question is about performing as graceful a shutdown as possible given the apt upgrade command currently running needs to be terminated soon so that a shutdown command can be given before the backup battery runs out.

Most important detail I want is to ensure sync is performed BEFORE the OS dies... Outside of that detail; I'd avoid breaking any package/process that will impact booting (and many boot writes don't complete to end of upgrade process, so if there is any risk of power failure I'd not start the upgrade!)..   If it was me, I'd consider what packages were being upgraded & go from there.. I always read what is being updated.. so I'd rely on that detail.. Beyond that can be specific. I had an initrd update on a box take >15 mins as the install is unusual, so each box can be unique in needs

ps:  don't forget you can command the kernel to sync via SysRq commands (you've not provided Ubuntu product/release specifics, as these will impact what is enabled by default; as well as some settings being set/influenced by your install media not just current release)
